# Is there something special I have to do to override WebViewClient.ShouldInterceptRequest for jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, android, jquery, xamarin

I am developing a hybrid android app, using Xamarin, and have run into a problem. I am using a webview and a custom routing engine to server razor pages. This all works correctly. My problem is jQuery get requests to the C# backend.

I can currently see WebViewClient.ShouldInterceptRequest trigger on a jQuery Get (it hits a breakpoint), assemble the correct data, and return a response, but when it gets back to the javascript side of things, jQuery just fails with a status of 0 (should be 200), and an error message of "error".

Various online resources seem to think that this is due to cross site scripting being blocked, but I am fairly sure that that is not (or at least, shouldn't) be the case, as the jQuery get request is just requesting a URL that has the same domain. So I guess if it is something blocking what it thinks is XSS, then I need to know what part of the URL is considered for this (I assume it is the domain, or, more specifically, the part before the 3rd slash, for instance, http://www.google.com/).

Thanks for your help.

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, to do this, you need to set these things:

```
        webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
```

in the activity in your android project.